# Why isn't my Main element to the right of my nav bar when on a computer full screen?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a code pen and am having an issue where initially my main element would be exactly to the right of my nav bar (on the left side with height = 100%), but not it is overlapped by the nav bar, even though I added a margin-left earlier wide enough to allow the main to be seen. Here is the CSS code:

```css
   html,
    body {
      min-width: 290px;
      color: hsla(214, 100%, 39%, 1);
      font-family: "Germania One", Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 17px;
      line-height: 1.25;
      background-color: hsla(239, 60%, 40%, 0.49);
    }
    
    h1 {
      color: black;
    }
    
    code {
      background-color: hsla(179, 8%, 40%, 0.49);
      border-radius: 3px;
      color: white;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
      white-space: pre;
      position: relative;
      word-break: normal;
      word-wrap: normal;
      line-height: 1.5;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 15px;
    }
    #navbar {
      z-index: 1;
      position: fixed;
      background-color: hsla(246, 81%, 24%, 1);
      min-width: 290px;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      width: 300px;
      height: 100%;
      border-right: solid;
      border-color: hsla(264, 80%, 39%, 1);
    }
    
    header {
      color: white;
      font-size: 30px;
      margin: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 1.8em;
      font-weight: thin;
    }
    
    #navbar a {
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    #navbar ul {
      list-style: none;
      height: 88%;
      overflow-y: auto;
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    
    #navbar li {
      border: 1px solid;
      border-bottom-width: 0px;
      padding: 8px;
      padding-left: 45px;
      position: relative;
      left: -50px;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    #main-doc {
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: 310px;
      padding: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 110px;
    }
    
    #main-doc header {
      text-align: left;
      margin: 0px;
    }
    
    section article {
      margin: 15px;
      font-size: 0.96em;
    }
    
    section li {
      margin: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
    }
    
    #Boulder-img {
      width: 80%;
    }
    
    #Sherpas-img {
      width: 90%;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 815px) {
      /* For mobile phones: */
      #navbar ul {
        border: 1px solid;
        height: 207px;
      }
      code {
        overflow-x: scroll;
      }
      #navbar {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
        max-height: 275px;
        border: none;
        z-index: 1;
        border-bottom: 2px solid;
      }
      #main-doc {
        position: relative;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-top: 270px;
      }
      #main-doc section {
        color: black;
        /*     padding-top: 240px; */
      }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
      #navbar {
        font-size: .75em;
      }
      #navbar ul {
        height: 222px;
      }
      }
      #main-doc {
        margin-left: -10px;
      }
      code {
        margin-left: -20px;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 15px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 45px;
        min-width: 233px;
      }
    }
```

```html
    <nav id="navbar">
  <header>
    FCC Technical Documentation</header>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#Explanation" class="nav-link">Explanation</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Early_Life" class="nav-link">Early Life</a></li>
    <li><a href="#First_Move" class="nav-link">First Move</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Some_Technical_Documentation" class="nav-link">Some Technical Documentation</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Present_Day" class="nav-link">Present Day</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<main id="main-doc">
  <section class="main-section" id="Explanation">
    <header>
      Explanation
    </header>
    <article>
      <p>
        Introduction paragraph
        <br>
        <code>
        &ltcode&gt
        <u>insert example code here</u>
        &lt/code&gt
      </code>
        <br>
        <p>It looks like I will have to do 5 of these code elements in the project. In order to display the symbol "&lt", I have to type
          <br>
          <code>
          &+l+t
        </code>
          <br> using those characters above without the plus signs. "&gt" is made by using the following in the same way:
          <br>
          <code>
          &+g+t
        </code>
          <br> I don't know how to display those characters together without it automatically displaying as those carrot symbols. I will ask on StackOverFlow (coding website/forum).
        </p>
        <p>
          I could do a documentation page describing what I already know and will use to make this page but I can't be bothered :p.
        </p>
        <p>
          So I posted my question on StackOverFlow, perhaps I will update in this section (sorry if it is long) if I get an answer. I've gotten the idea to use the code elements to do small features within the page to explain how I made certain parts of it. I also
          read through the prompt completely (glanced over it), and it seems that that was the only road bump. Thanks and enjoy.
          <br>:)
        </p>
    </article>
  </section>

  <section class="main-section" id="Early_Life">
    <header>
      Early Life
    </header>
    <article>
      <p>
        Early life paragraph
        
      </p>
      <h1>first photo header</h1>
      <img src="" alt="" id="">
      <p>
        <h1>header for story</h1>
        story paragraph
      </p>
      <img src="" alt="" id="">
      <p>To code in the photos above, I used the img element. The coding goes as follows:
        <br>
        <code>
      &ltimg src="linkofimagegoeshere" alt="descriptionincasephotofails" id="goodtohaveidtoalterappearancewithCSS"&gt
    </code>
      </p>
    </article>
  </section>

  <section class="main-section" id="First_Move">
    <header>
      First Move</header>
    <article>
      <p>
        first move paragraph
      </p>
      <p>
        I later moved to a small town in blank for high school
      </p>
    </article>
  </section>

  <section class="main-section" id="Some_Technical_Documentation">
    <header>
      Some Technical Documentation
    </header>
    <article>
      <p>
        So it turns out that you can display the code of how to code in a carrot symbol inside of a coding element without having what you type turn into a carrot itself. Sorry if that made no sense, this is hard to describe unless it is seen visually. Here is
        the code that you can enter in order to show &+l+t and &+g+t without them turning into carrots (basically ampersand has it's own sort of reference code).
        <br>
        <code>
        &amp;ltcode&amp;gt turns into &ltcode&gt
      </code>
        <br> In order to prevent &+l+t (etc.) to turn into a carrot, the ampersand code is &+amp;+lt or gt. Please don't send me further down this rabbithole. I don't want to learn how to display that one without the plus signs.
      </p>
      <p>If it appears that some of my CSS code matches that of the example, it is that I am following along with the code as to learn what all of it means and how it works. I'll set most of the copied values the same but I like to adjust them to learn more
        about the associated properties. I definitely did all of the HTML by myself and half of the CSS alone. Once I got stumped, however, I looked at the example's code. I was trying to use flex boxes to make the nav bar, but it turns out that just
        using absolute/relative position with margin, padding, top, left, etc. works better.</p>
    </article>
  </section>

  <section class="main-section" id="Present_Day">
    <header>
      Present Day
    </header>
    <article>
      <p>
        final paragraph
      </p>
      <p>On top of that, I am also: <br>
        <ul>
          <li>lifting weights</li>
          <li>walking and jogging two miles daily</li>
          <li>playing guitar</li>
          <li>learning to code</li>
          <li>making weekly videos documenting my journey</li>
          <li>blank</li>
          <br> and
          <br>
          <li>blank</li>
          <br> I'm hoping to get back to my social life as well.
        </ul>
        I've gone a long way already but I have much longer to go.
        <br> Thanks for reading! :)
      </p>
    </article>
  </section>
</main>
```

I am still new to all of this and honestly don't know where the issue would be so I pasted the whole css code, except for my font import.

Comment: Post your HTML as well please. We need a [mcve]

Comment: I am also getting 1 fail on the freecodecamp test:  "1. On regular sized devices (laptops, desktops), the element with id="navbar" should be shown on the left half of the screen. It should always be visible to the user and should remain stationary. You may need to enlarge the viewport or zoom out to ensure the navbar doesn't scroll with the page content."

Comment: It is shown on the left half of the screen. It is visible and stationary. I am confused. Perhaps it is related to the main element, I'm not sure. It was all seeming to work and then I added in some queries and that's why weird things happened.

Comment: Frankly, comments are of little use to us here unless you post the full reproducible example in your question.  IF it is relevant edit and update your question instead.

Comment: Can I link my codepen?

Comment: Please paste it IN the question if at all possible so it is HERE and the question becomes useful over time.  I formatted as a snippet so that may assist you.  See the note by @j08691 for more details

Comment: Could you elaborate as to what a snippet is? And yes I will edit in the HTML right now. I just have to remove some of the text.

Comment: Please add HTML or else provide the link of codepen

Comment: Yes I've posted the HTML now. Excuse me for being new to this website. I'm learning. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: It's OK to learn, I suspected some newness hence why I did not vote to close as opposed to guidance to make it a great question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had an additional `}` on the `(max-width: 400px)` breakpoint that was overriding a previous `margin-left` rule with `margin-left: -10px`

```css
html,
body {
  min-width: 290px;
  color: hsla(214, 100%, 39%, 1);
  font-family: "Germania One", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 1.25;
  background-color: hsla(239, 60%, 40%, 0.49);
}

h1 {
  color: black;
}

code {
  background-color: hsla(179, 8%, 40%, 0.49);
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: pre;
  position: relative;
  word-break: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 15px;
}

#navbar {
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: hsla(246, 81%, 24%, 1);
  min-width: 290px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: solid;
  border-color: hsla(264, 80%, 39%, 1);
}

header {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  font-weight: thin;
}

#navbar a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#navbar ul {
  list-style: none;
  height: 88%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#navbar li {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  padding: 8px;
  padding-left: 45px;
  position: relative;
  left: -50px;
  width: 100%;
}

#main-doc {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 310px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 110px;
}

#main-doc header {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0px;
}

section article {
  margin: 15px;
  font-size: 0.96em;
}

section li {
  margin: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
}

#Boulder-img {
  width: 80%;
}

#Sherpas-img {
  width: 90%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 815px) {
  /* For mobile phones: */
  #navbar ul {
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 207px;
  }
  code {
    overflow-x: scroll;
  }
  #navbar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 275px;
    border: none;
    z-index: 1;
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
  }
  #main-doc {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 270px;
  }
  #main-doc section {
    color: black;
    /*     padding-top: 240px; */
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  #navbar {
    font-size: .75em;
  }
  #navbar ul {
    height: 222px;
  }
 /* } You had this closing bracket here*/
  #main-doc {
    margin-left: -10px;
  }
  code {
    margin-left: -20px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 45px;
    min-width: 233px;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
  <header>
    FCC Technical Documentation</header>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#Explanation" class="nav-link">Explanation</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Early_Life" class="nav-link">Early Life</a></li>
    <li><a href="#First_Move" class="nav-link">First Move</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Some_Technical_Documentation" class="nav-link">Some Technical Documentation</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Present_Day" class="nav-link">Present Day</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<main id="main-doc">
  <section class="main-section" id="Explanation">
    <header>
      Explanation
    </header>
    <article>
      <p>
        Introduction paragraph
        <br>
        <code>
        &ltcode&gt
        <u>insert example code here</u>
        &lt/code&gt
      </code>
        <br>
        <p>It looks like I will have to do 5 of these code elements in the project. In order to display the symbol "&lt", I have to type
          <br>
          <code>
          &+l+t
        </code>
          <br> using those characters above without the plus signs. "&gt" is made by using the following in the same way:
          <br>
          <code>
          &+g+t
        </code>
          <br> I don't know how to display those characters together without it automatically displaying as those carrot symbols. I will ask on StackOverFlow (coding website/forum).
        </p>
        <p>
          I could do a documentation page describing what I already know and will use to make this page but I can't be bothered :p.
        </p>
        <p>
          So I posted my question on StackOverFlow, perhaps I will update in this section (sorry if it is long) if I get an answer. I've gotten the idea to use the code elements to do small features within the page to explain how I made certain parts of it. I also
          read through the prompt completely (glanced over it), and it seems that that was the only road bump. Thanks and enjoy.
          <br>:)
        </p>
    </article>
  </section>

  <section class="main-section" id="Early_Life">
    <header>
      Early Life
    </header>
    <article>
      <p>
        Early life paragraph

      </p>
      <h1>first photo header</h1>
      <img src="" alt="" id="">
      <p>
        <h1>header for story</h1>
        story paragraph
      </p>
      <img src="" alt="" id="">
      <p>To code in the photos above, I used the img element. The coding goes as follows:
        <br>
        <code>
      &ltimg src="linkofimagegoeshere" alt="descriptionincasephotofails" id="goodtohaveidtoalterappearancewithCSS"&gt
    </code>
      </p>
    </article>
  </section>

  <section class="main-section" id="First_Move">
    <header>
      First Move</header>
    <article>
      <p>
        first move paragraph
      </p>
      <p>
        I later moved to a small town in blank for high school
      </p>
    </article>
  </section>

  <section class="main-section" id="Some_Technical_Documentation">
    <header>
      Some Technical Documentation
    </header>
    <article>
      <p>
        So it turns out that you can display the code of how to code in a carrot symbol inside of a coding element without having what you type turn into a carrot itself. Sorry if that made no sense, this is hard to describe unless it is seen visually. Here is
        the code that you can enter in order to show &+l+t and &+g+t without them turning into carrots (basically ampersand has it's own sort of reference code).
        <br>
        <code>
        &amp;ltcode&amp;gt turns into &ltcode&gt
      </code>
        <br> In order to prevent &+l+t (etc.) to turn into a carrot, the ampersand code is &+amp;+lt or gt. Please don't send me further down this rabbithole. I don't want to learn how to display that one without the plus signs.
      </p>
      <p>If it appears that some of my CSS code matches that of the example, it is that I am following along with the code as to learn what all of it means and how it works. I'll set most of the copied values the same but I like to adjust them to learn more
        about the associated properties. I definitely did all of the HTML by myself and half of the CSS alone. Once I got stumped, however, I looked at the example's code. I was trying to use flex boxes to make the nav bar, but it turns out that just
        using absolute/relative position with margin, padding, top, left, etc. works better.</p>
    </article>
  </section>

  <section class="main-section" id="Present_Day">
    <header>
      Present Day
    </header>
    <article>
      <p>
        final paragraph
      </p>
      <p>On top of that, I am also: <br>
        <ul>
          <li>lifting weights</li>
          <li>walking and jogging two miles daily</li>
          <li>playing guitar</li>
          <li>learning to code</li>
          <li>making weekly videos documenting my journey</li>
          <li>blank</li>
          <br> and
          <br>
          <li>blank</li>
          <br> I'm hoping to get back to my social life as well.
        </ul>
        I've gone a long way already but I have much longer to go.
        <br> Thanks for reading! :)
      </p>
    </article>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help man! Didn't know that something like that could cause such an issue! :p

Comment: No problem, what happens is that the closing bracket was closing the media query as well; so everything after that was overriding the original css rules above

Comment: Makes total sense. To be honest I did 3/4 of it without looking at the example code but I got stumped and sick of trying to apply a flexbox to the navbar to makes it work the way it does now without a flexbox. So I looked at the example code to see how they did it. Had to do with absolute/relative positioning/top/left/padding/margin/ and media queries I believe.